# How to change the text of Adaptive Card response confirmation for MS Teams bot app

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Adaptive cards for bots in MS Teams now appear to be displaying a confirmation of "your response was sent to the app" message when a button on the card is clicked.

I want to display different message whenever i click different buttons. Is there any possible way to do it. Any other suggestion to achieve the same is welcomed.
[Bot Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maqBx.png)

I tried changing the text but i did not find any relevant document.

Comment: Whenever users submit information via Action.Submit or Action.Execute to your bot it will show a success indicator upon completion of the invoke call. There is no such way to change/modify/disable it. It is by design.

Comment: To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).